# scheduleAtFixedRate executes fast

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm using method scheduleAtFixedRate in my program (Timer class ). It runs every one second, but sometimes this method becomes really fast ( it's executing 3 - 4 per second ).

However i did some research on web and i found this:

Copied from android developer's page:

> With fixed-rate execution, the start time of each successive run of a task is scheduled without regard for when the previous run took place. This may result in a series of bunched-up runs (one launched immediately after another) if delays prevent the timer from starting tasks on time.

I need fixed timer. It should run only **once per x time** without any fast executions. Is there any alternative to scheduleAtFixedRate method or, i need to be satisfied with this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead, with more than one thread if your task can take more than 1 sec to run.

The syntax is very similar to Timer but it is a more robust and flexible API.

Answer (score 1):

The method schedule in Timer class could be considered even though it does not guarantee that the task will be executed once per 'x' period of time.

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime,  long period)
```

Atleast it would not have repeated execution like the way you said.